# Как при нажатии на ссылку показывать блок с затемнением фона?

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку появлялся блок в центре экрана. Когда блок появляется задний фон должен быть немного затемненный.

Comment: Типичное popup окно: https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/69352/

Answer (score 4):

Простейший пример модального окна

```js
function ShowModal(elId) {
  var modalAll = document.getElementById(elId);
  modalAll.style.display = "flex";
}

function HideModal() {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('modal-all')) {
    event.currentTarget.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal-all {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>какой-то текст</div>
<div>какой-то текст</div>
<div>какой-то текст</div>

<a href="javascript://" onclick="ShowModal('m1')" class="btn btn-info">открываем модальное окно</a>

<div id="m1" class="modal-all" onclick="HideModal()">
  <div class="modal">
    окно, окно, окно
  </div>
</div>
```